# Wizard view for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, wizard

I want to implement a wizard view that have to apply the following requirements:

- several steps (configurable)
- each step has to be a stand-alone UIView
- back, previous, finish buttons
- indicator that must show on each step we are

It must not be some navigation-style implementation (using UINavigationController) just view which I can place somewhere on the another UIView.

Any suggestions & best practices how to implement this task?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a modal view. You should just configure a view as you like and display it modally from the view controller. It will then appear above the other views and trap all touches. If you need to create the illusion of various "pages" you would need to programmatically add buttons, text fields etc and then remove them as needed.

However, you might want to rethink this design. It's all good and well to have a wizard in a dialog view on a non-mobile screen with plenty of visual real estate but you really don't have that much space on a mobile screen. If you leave the backing view visible this will rob the wizard view of most of its area. If you expand the wizard view to a useful size, you might as well use a full screen view anyway.